# Input variable Python

Tags: python, variables

How to print variable typed by user, for example user types

```
var = input("Type variable name: ")
```

and program finds that var. and prints it

Sorry if this question already exists but i didn't find it.
(Also sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You should create some sort of mapping between *strings* and the *objects* you are interested in. The use should have no knowledge of any *variables*. Just use a `dict`

Comment: Simply: print(var)

Comment: To echo @Sheri, once it's saved as a variable, all variables can be printed the same way in python, with `print()`. One nitpick with the posted code: `input()` already returns a string by default, so there's no need to cast it to a string with `str(input())`. If there's some other scenario you need, please provide a [mcve] for better answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: @G.Anderson yes you are right i have edited and removed str()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
variableName = input("Type var name: ")

try:
  print(globals()[variableName])
except:
  print("Variable not found")
```